# How to make image button in JavaFX without any style (just an image)?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I wanted to add an image on button in javafx, but I have got the following:

[image]

But I need a button with only image and with no default style, like borders, background color etc.

The thing I want to implement looks like this:

[image]

How can I make it?